# Canonical hyperreal numbers

Tags: nonstandard-analysis

The hyperreal numbers are constructed by any free ultrafilter.
We know that  we can't exhibit a concrete example of a free ultrafilter on natural numbers ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885801/example-of-a-free-ultrafilter-on-natural-numbers)).
Is it possible to give a canonical hyperreal numbers also if it is not possibile to give explicitly a free ultrafilter?

Comment: What does it mean for a number to be "canonical" here?

Comment: ... and what is wrong with the 'obvious' response of "You can give a hyperreal number (in any of this family of models) by giving a sequence of real numbers".

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225546/a-definable-hyperreal-system) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402002/why-continuum-hypothesis-implies-the-unique-hyperreal-system-ast-bbb-r).

Comment: When I say canonical I mean the possibility to choice one of the isomorphic contructions of hyperreals